# Some USB ports suddenly stop working (not only mouse/keyboard)

Tags: usb, kernel, hardware

From one day to the next a number of USB ports no longer work in Ubuntu. In the BIOS I can use my mouse and keyboard. And in Windows I have no problem either, it sees all devices.

But when I start Ubuntu, all the lights of some of the USB devices go out. USB sticks and USB camera can no longer be used. Some remain on such as the USB Bluetooth and USB WiFi are still working.

When I run `lsusb` in the terminal I no longer see these ports.

I really don't get it. How come Ubuntu doesn't see the hardware anymore. Yesterday there was no problem and Windows does not have this problem. How do I solve this?

Ubuntu 21.04, 64-bit, 5.11.0-44-generic

*Just to be clear, **ALL** my USB devices have this problem on those ports. So no reference to people who only have problems with their mouse and keyboard.**

Comment: Have you disabled Fast Startup in Windows? If not then do that and shutdown. Boot Ubuntu and try again. Report back.

Comment: I replace the entire hard drive every time.

Comment: So, you aren't dual-booting? Even if that's the case the same problem with some devices can occur depending on how you exit Windows with Fast Startup on. And please when questioned for clarity make sure to answer accordingly. And update the question with [edit]s whenever needed.

Comment: I fix it  by rebooting , but it seems you would have tried that.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I literally came here to ask the exact same question.  My hardware is a Mac Pro.  This occurs with both the built-in USB ports and a generic USB 3.0/USB-C card.  It worked once, then on a reboot, Ubuntu silently upgraded my kernel without my permission, and left me unable to boot (because my boot drive is on USB.  None of the ports on the card work.  None of the build-in USB-C ports work.  Only the two built-in USB-3 (A) ports work.  This kernel should never have shipped.  This is a P0 showstopper.

Comment: I've filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956849 asking them to pull the linux 5.11.0-44-generic kernel package ASAP.  In the meantime, the right fix is to roll your installation back to a previously installed Linux kernel.

Comment: @dgatwood & others, if the issue only impacts *hirsute* there is a good chance it won't be fixed given 21.04 is already within it's last week of life  (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html)

Comment: It doesn't.  I'm on 20.04 LTS.

Comment: 20.04.4 is soon to be released for installed systems; the 5.13 kernel has already replaced 5.11 on daily ISOs for *focal* - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/20220115/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest so as stated 5.11 is in it's last days @dgatwood

Comment: @uiverc Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: FYI:  @pierrely  I gave a specific *daily* image where the date was part of the URL... it would have been available max ~3 days before it was *dropped* having been replaced by later *daily* images...  You can use https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest to view the current *daily* data; but it'll of course changed to the specific *daily* I provided in prior comment (*and what's in the file today will not likely match what's in it tomorrow.. why I'd have used a specific daily date*)

Comment: I don't think this question is of value any longer; the 5.11 kernel is EOL for *focal* or 20.04 (& [Ubuntu 21.04 where it came from is now EOL too](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html), installed systems should already have upgraded to the 5.13 kernel, where the problem may or may not exist.  @Wobbo  you should check to see if this issue still occurs as you won't be using the 5.11 kernel any longer.